# Excel connection to database, problem when shared in One Drive

Tags: sql-server, excel

Not sure if this is the correct forum but here goes. Very new to databases so apologies ahead of time if I don't provide enough info.

I have a Microsoft SQL Server Database created with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18, I connected Excel to it to analyse the data and saved that workbook in a shared One Drive folder. Works fine on my computer but the other users cannot refresh the data from the database. I've exhausted all my online search options to figure out how to fix this. I don't know if the database is on a cloud server or if that matters.

Error message is; [Datasource.Error] Microsoft SQL: A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider; SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

The database does allow for remote connections, I checked that.

I'm comfortable with Excel but I'm new to databases, only worked with Access in the past. Anyone know of the "best" way to have a database we can all (4 users currently) connect to while also connecting Excel to it.

I don't understand the pricing plans for Azure, AWS etc. plus they seem to be way more than what I need.

Doesn't have to be a free option but a set monthly fee with no surprises would work if a server is the issue. It's a relatively small amount of data, currently maybe 100 rows, 24 columns.

The option I last came across was Godaddy web hosting had a database option, don't if this is a good option or not. I signed up for Elephantsql but I haven't figured out how to use that to host the database, creating one in elephant itself seems to use only code rather than the way I created the database in Microsoft.

Thanks in advance for any help, going to go close my 25 google search tabs now.....

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you realy need an SQL-Server for dataset auf 100 rows and 24 columns?
I would try do store the date in a shared Excel-File in Onedrive an connect to this.

Best regards
Chris

**EDIT**
If you want to connect to Private-OneDrive File you should use a WEB-Connector instead of a "File"-Connector.

Your Source should be like this:

```
=Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://onedrive.live.com/download?resid=AAAXXXXAAA&authkey=BBBXXXXBBB&em=CCCXXXXCCC&app=Excel"), null, true)
```

You have to replace the **AAAXXXXAAAA; BBBXXXXBBB and CCCXXXXCCC** with informations from the embedded-link of your XLSX-File: 
1) open OneDrive in WEB 
2) Select you file and right-click 
3) click "embedded" 
4) in the right pane you find the embedded-link
5) find there the **resid; authkey and em**

[OneDrive GetEmbeddedLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J9KC.png)

Comment: I did do it that way at first using sheet 1 as the database and the other sheets to read from that data. The setup is using answers in 1 column to populate data in the other sheets depending on the answer, at first I used Microsoft Query to connect the tables in Excel and that works fine on my computer but that also would not work when shared on One Drive. The other users couldn't refresh the data.

That's why I thought the database option would be a better choice. also the data will grow to thousands of rows over time so I wanted to start out in a way that would scale.

Comment: Which Excel Version do you use?
Do/Can you use PowerQuery ? Do you use OneDrive for Business or Privat?

Comment: Excel for Microsoft 365 but other users are using different versions, not sure what versions though, sorry. I'm testing power query now to see if that will work. One Drive is personal not business. Thanks.

I would still be interested in getting a database to work as eventually I would add more tables and queries.

Comment: Using power query, the error returned when another user tries to refresh is; [DataSource.Error] Could not find a part of the path 'C;\Users\and then the file name on my computer .xlsx'.

Comment: To connect to a private OneDrive File you should use a WEB-Link instead of a "File"-Link. Your Source should be like this:
'=Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://onedrive.live.com/download?resid=AAAXXXXAAA&authkey=BBBXXXXBBB&em=CCCXXXXCCC&app=Excel"), null, true)'
You have to replace the **AAAXXXXAAAA; BBBXXXXBBB and CCCXXXXCCC** 
with informations from the embedded Lind of your XLSX-File:
1) open OneDrive in WEB
2) Select you File and right-click
3) click "embedded" 
4) in the right pane you find the embedded-Code
5) find there the **resid; authkey and em**

Comment: The Source-Code in my last comment is displayed incorrect, I try it again here:
Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https:     //onedrive.live.com/download?resid=AAAXXXXAAA&authkey=BBBXXXXBBB&em=CCCXXXXCCC&app=Excel" ), null, true)

Comment: First test looks to have worked! I connected by downloading rather than embed, went to my downloads in chrome, copied the url from there. In excel get data from web and copied the url there. So far that's worked. I need to test with some more tables but with this knowledge now I should be able to make it all work. Excel is enough for what we need right now giving me plenty time to learn a lot more about databases.

Thanks so much Chris, this is a massive help!

Comment: I'm happy that I could help :-). If you are satisfied with my answer, maybe you can vote it.
Best Regards Chris